# What to do when a specific user's posts are always flagged for a closing?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I have been surfing the close votes portion of the review queue and after going through maybe $5$ - $10$ posts, I noticed that a specific user's questions kept coming up to be closed.

Most of these questions were not recently asked. I was wondering if there is a possibility of ill-intent, if someone has seen this kind of behavior before and if there is a system in place to stop someone from going through a user's questions and flagging them as a kind of harassment?

NOTE: Most of the questions which came up were either well received or I felt there was nothing wrong with them.

Comment: It certainly sounds as if a particular user was targeted, which is against the spirit of SE policies.  I have not seen this myself, but if you think a user is being targetted, I suggest flagging one of those Questions for moderator attention with a note explaining the concern.

Comment: Or it's possible that this user posted a series of low-quality questions in quick succession because homework deadlines and final exams are coming up, and several users independently saw the questions as worth closing. Who knows! Are the questions recent or not?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Most of the questions weren't recent and in fact, some are very well received.

Comment: I should've realized a lot sooner that I was doing something wrong. I'm sorry.

Comment: Somehow related: The answers to question 1 in http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/337571/2016-stack-overflow-moderator-election-qa-questionnaire

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming that this is a case of one user serially close voting/flagging the questions of another specific user, the main thing to do is to honestly review each question independently when you see them in the review queue, or otherwise come across these questions.

The system has checks and balances to prevent almost all malicious close voting/flagging. The most basic check is the requirement of multiple users to close a question (excepting when a moderator votes to close, or a gold tag-badge holder votes to close as a duplicate). This first check makes it generally unlikely that questions are closed without any justification. And close votes expire after four days if the question is not closed in the meantime, meaning that there is a limited window during which the malicious intent can amount to anything.

Even if closed, recently closed questions appear in the `/tools?tab=close` page (for 10K users) for further scrutiny. And the community has developed methods (the [C.R.U.D.E.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/2165/c-r-u-d-e) chat room, as well as the [Requests for Reopen & Undeletion Votes, etc.](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/19042) meta thread) to expedite the reopening of questions which should not be closed.

In all, I view "serial" close voting/flagging as a rather limited issue not generally requiring special reactions. Users simply reviewing these questions individually and honestly as they appear in the review queue will almost always be enough to thwart any purely malicious intent.